# How to return the last 10 entries using clojurewerkz?

Tags: clojure

I want to fetch 10 latest entries from elasticsearch database.
For this, I am using:

```
(require '[clojurewerkz.elastisch.rest.document :as esd])

(esd/search es-conn 
                    index_name
                     mapping
                    :query (q/prefix :column value)
                    :from 0 :size 10)
```

This only fetches the oldest 10 entries from the document.

I want to know how to fetch the latest entries....
I mean which parameter should be passed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `_timestamp` fields on your document:

https://www.elastic.co/search?q=timestamp

Then you can sort on that and limit the size to 10.